# Can I travel within the Europe while awaiting my French resident permit (I have a 3 month work visa)?

Tags: france, residence-cards

I'm a US citizen that's moving to France to work for a French company.  I've received a work permit and have filed an application for a French residency permit. The HR in my company insists that I can't leave France while my permit application is pending, everyone else (including American coworkers) tell me the exact opposite.

Comment: Even if you could legally travel elsewhere in Europe while your French residency permit is pending, why would you want to do this? You'd be seen as disregarding the company's directions, and I'd think doing so would jeopardize your employment.

Comment: You can certainly travel to other Schengen countries as far as Schengen law is concerned.  The problem is probably that under French law if you leave France while your application is pending you will be seen as abandoning the application, and if the authorities get wind of this they might require you to submit a new application.

Comment: A few questions to clarify the situation. 

What type of visa did you get? I'm assuming it's a work visa D (visa long séjour - valant titre de séjour - also known as a VLS-TS)? Does your visa say "carte de séjour à solliciter dans les 2 mois suivant l'arrivée"?

Also, are you already in France or are you just about to arrive? You say you have filed an application for a French residency permit? I'm assuming it's with the OFII?

Comment: @ar5975- sorry, just saw your comment now.  It is a Type D visa for multiple entries (says "MULT"  for "Number of Entries").  It does say  "carte de séjour à solliciter dans les 2 mois suivant l'arrivée."  I'm already in France.  I'm assuming my HR has already filed my residency application (they were supposed to) but the person responsible is on vacation so I can't get than info.